# How to declare generic class generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, containers, type-inference

I m trying to design a way to declare a function that can return a Promise or a rxjs Observable or a most Stream with the specific return type but I don't know a proper way to declare this function in typescript.

In general I want in my code something like this:

```
class Action<T> {
    dispatcher: Function
    constructor(dist) {
        this.dispatcher = dist
    }

    f = <T>(s: string): T<string> => this.dispatcher('hello'+s)
}
```

> In this way I get the error: 'T is not generic'

for me T can be a Promise or a Observable or a Stream

If I was able to have something similar to this I can declare a specific dispatcher that return the value how I want it based on how I declared it

```
const promiseDispacher = (x:any)=>Promise.resolve(x)
const observableDispacher = (x:any)=>Observable.of(x)
```

What I want to have is the ability of when I call the function f be able to used in different ways

```
 const a = new Action<Promise>(promiseDistpacher)
 a.f('random string').then((s: string)=>{
   ....
 })
```

or

```
 const a = new Action<Observable>(observableDistpacher)
 a.f('random string').subscribe((s: string)=>{
   ....
 })
```

**UPDATED**

`f` is a function that executes some operations and use the dispatcher to wrap the result in the specific `T` (Promise or Stream) and returned back to the class that executes the function

Comment: Wait, what is `f` supposed to be?  You seem to be treating it both as a function that returns a `T` (if I understand your implementation of `Action`) but also as a `T` itself (when you do `a.f.then()` etc).  In any case you probably want to make `Action` generic like `class Action<T>`.  But the specifics escape me without more of an understanding of what `f` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @jcalz   yes, you are right . Action class  is the one that is going to be generic and describe that the dispatcher is going to return a Promise or a Stream, but how do I declare the function `f` ?

Comment: If `f` is a *function*, then why are you trying to access a `then()` method on it?  It is either a function, or (say) a promise... not both.  Which one is it?

Comment: it is a function that return a promise or a observable based on the declaration of the class and the distpatcher

Comment: So then please edit your question so you are not calling `a.f.then(...)`.  If `f` is a function you need to call it, as in `a.f("something").then(...)`.  Otherwise I think there is still some confusion here about the difference between a function that returns a thing and the thing itself.

Comment: And what is `s` in `a.f(s)`?  Please be sure your code constitutes a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer this despite not really being sure what you're doing.  As a first shot, let's make `T` the generic type returned by the passed-in dispatcher, something like `Promise<any>` or `Observable<any>` or [`ReadableStream<any>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream):

```
class Action<T> {
  dispatcher: (x: any) => T;
  constructor(dist: (x: any) => T) {
    this.dispatcher = dist
  }
  f = (s: string) => this.dispatcher('hello' + s);
}

const promiseDispatcher = (x: any) => Promise.resolve(x)
const a = new Action(promiseDispatcher);
a.f("random string").then((s: string) => {
  // ...
}); // works
```

This works now, and the type of `f` for an `Action<T>` is inferred to be of type `(s: string) => T`, and since `a` is an `Action<Promise<any>>`, then `a.f(s)` is a `Promise<any>`.  Note that despite `f` having a `T` in its return type, `f` itself is not what you'd consider a generic function.  The generic parameter is on the *class*, and once you have a concrete instance of the class, its `f` function is a concrete function type also.

---

One issue here is that you probably don't really want `a.f(s)` to be a `Promise<any>`, but would rather see a `Promise<string>`.  It turns out that since TypeScript doesn't currently support [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) very much, there's no *general* way to say to make `T` something like `Promise` or `Observable` or `ReadableStream`, which are themselves generic types.  With [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) you can pick a few hardcoded types like `Promise<any>`, `Observable<any>`, and `ReadableStream<any>` and convert them to `Promise<string>`, `Observable<string>`, and `ReadableStream<string>`, respectively:

```
type AppliedToString<T> =
  T extends Promise<any> ? Promise<string> :
  T extends Observable<any> ? Observable<string> :
  T extends ReadableStream<any> ? ReadableStream<string> :
  T;
```

Now if we [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to those hardcoded types and use the type function above, we should get something like the typing you want for `f`:

```
// constrain T
class Action<T extends Promise<any> | Observable<any> | ReadableStream<any>> {
  dispatcher: (x: any) => T;
  constructor(dist: (x: any) => T) {
    this.dispatcher = dist
  }
  // assert return type of f as AppliedToString<T>
  f = (s: string) => this.dispatcher('hello' + s) as AppliedToString<T>;
}
const promiseDispatcher = (x: any) => Promise.resolve(x);
const a = new Action(promiseDispatcher);
a.f("random string").then((s: string) => {
  // ...
}); // works
```

Now if you inspect `a.f`'s return type you will see it is a `Promise<string>`.

The downside to doing it this way is you need to maintain a hardcoded list, and it's also not particularly typesafe, since it will allow you to pass in a dispatcher that returns a `Promise<number>` and treat it like a `Promise<string>`... which will explode at runtime.

---

If I were trying to be simpler and more typesafe, I'd limit `T` to `Promise<string>`, `Observable<string>`, or `ReadableStream<string>` and forget the mapping, but require the passed-in dispatcher to take a `string` and return a `T`:

```
class Action<T extends Promise<string> | Observable<string> | ReadableStream<string>> {
  dispatcher: (x: string) => T;
  constructor(dist: (x: string) => T) {
    this.dispatcher = dist
  }
  f = (s: string) => this.dispatcher('hello' + s);
}
// note that x is type string in this:
const promiseDispatcher = (x: string) => Promise.resolve(x)
const a = new Action(promiseDispatcher);
a.f("random string").then((s: string) => {
  // ...
})
```

---

Okay, hope that one or more of those helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: I was trying to come up with a type inference for a container type but I can't figure out how to make the syntax work. For example you can infer the contained type for a specific container like `type GetContained<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never` but you can't infer the container for a specific contained type like `type GetContainer<T> = T extends (infer U)<string> ? U : never`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Now that I think about it, a container isn't really a type. It's just an incomplete template for creating a type, so you can't extract it like that... I realize now that my question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Your question definitely does make sense, but TypeScript doesn't really have a good answer for it.  A container type is of a higher [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)).  There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) which talks about adding support for higher-kinded types, but who knows if it will ever happen.  For now there's only the kludge of picking from a hardcoded list of containers, as I did above.

Comment: thanks for the answer! For now I will live with the solution that you provided